# React pass multiple properties and children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm new to React, typescript and nextjs and I'm trying to pass multiple properties to a component. But, I seem to override them.

For example I have this in my **_app.tsx**

```
function App({ Component, myProps }: MyAppProps): JSX.Element {
  const { ...props } = myProps;
  return (
    <MyStateProvider>
          <Component {...props} />{' '}
    </MyStateProvider>
  );
}
```

In MyStateProvider, I have this in **my-state-context.tsx**

```
export const MyStateProvider: React.FC<any> = ( {children}) => {
  const contextValue = doSomething();
  return (
    <MyStateContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </MyStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

However, I wish to something like this in my **_app.tsx**

```
function App({ Component, myProps }: MyAppProps): JSX.Element {
  const { ...props } = myProps;
  return (
    <MyStateProvider {...props}>
          <Component {...props} />{' '}
    </MyStateProvider>
  );
}
```

And this MyStateProvider in **my-state-context.tsx**

```
export const MyStateProvider: React.FC<any> = ( props, {children }) => {
  const contextValue = doSomething(props); // <-- trying to accomplish passing props
  return (
    <MyStateContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </MyStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: children are part of the props in react so you can get them via `props.children` or to make it look more fancy like this: `{ children, ...otherProps } = props`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
function App({ Component, ...myProps }: MyAppProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <MyStateProvider {...myProps}>
      <Component {...myProps} />
    </MyStateProvider>
  );
}
```

and in your provider, supposing that you are passing the component like this `<MyStateProvider Children={SomeComponent}/>`

```
// note that first letter of Children should be uppercase to behave as a component
export const MyStateProvider: React.FC<any> = ({Children, ...props}) => {
  const contextValue = doSomething({...props});
  return (
    <MyStateContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <Children />
    </MyStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

See [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-architecture-e3hf67?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I got it, doing `{ children, ...otherProps }` fixed it. Thanks everyone!